# Read multiline in folder and split info by "|' mark

Tags: vb.net

Whats the problem with this code?I have tryied a lot of things but is doesn'y work.It says :"Ilegal type of characters ".I t just has to identify the mark and delete the second part path.

```
  If File.Exists("c:\windows\wiaserv1.txt") Then
        Dim txtStream As New StreamReader("c:\windows\wiaserv1.txt") 'in fisier se afla : delete|"c:\windows\zzz.txt"
        Dim read As String
        Dim aa As String
        read = txtStream.ReadLine
        aa = Split(read, "|")(1)
        Do Until txtStream.EndOfStream
            Select Case Split(read, "|")(0)
                Case "delete"
                    File.Delete(aa)
            End Select
        Loop

    End If
```

Comment: Pre-.NET or .NET: they are very different environments: chose one.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Electricspider: I think Richard is referring to the fact that you have tagged your question with both vb.net and vb6. Those are two different languages. Based on your use of StreamReader, I think this is vb.net in which case you should remove the vb6 tag.

Comment: a sorry .but what about my problem??

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of your code. One problem is that you have `Do Until txtStream.EndOfStream` but nowhere in the loop do you read from txtStream, so either the loop will never execute, or it will never end. Another problem (and this might be the one you are asking about) is that if the line you read from the file has double quotes around the file path (as in the comment on the statement that declares txtStream), those double quotes need to be removed before passing the file path to File.Delete.

Comment: so how should i proceed?

Comment: i edited it like this now , im not sure , and i have modified the text also and youre right it loops to infinit :                                                            Do Until txtStream.Peek <> -1
                Select Case Split(read, "|")(0)
                    Case "delete"
                        File.Delete(aa)
                End Select
            Loop

Comment: hhow should i proceed next>?

Comment: If the code you posted is your actual code, you need to correct the logic so that you are reading from txtStream **inside** the loop that is checking for the end of the stream. If the text you are reading has double quotes around the file path, you can use String.Trim to remove them `File.Delete(aa.Trim({""""c}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like this:

```
Public Sub ProcessFile(filePath as String)
    If File.Exists(filePath) Then
        For Each pair In File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(Function(x) Split(x, "|"))
            Select Case pair(0).ToUpper
                Case "DELETE"
                    File.Delete(Replace(pair(1), Chr(34), String.Empty))
            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```